# Enabling service worker using workbox

Tags: webpack, progressive-web-apps, workbox

Working on a react PWA that uses webpack as build system. For service worker we are using [workbox](http://workboxjs.org) version 2.1.2.

- Having a GET api http://localhost:5000/dist/abc/123/ that responds with JSON. Registered the route with

  ```
  'use strict';
   importScripts('workbox-sw.prod.js');
   const workboxSW = new WorkboxSW({
      clientsClaim: true,
      skipWaiting: true
   });
   workboxSW.LOG_LEVEL = 'debug';
   workboxSW.precache([]);
   workboxSW.router.registerRoute(
            'http://localhost:5000/dist/abc/123',
             workboxSW.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate({
                   cacheName: 'apis',
                   cacheExpiration: {
                       maxEntries: 50,
                       maxAgeSeconds: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60
                   },
                   cacheableResponse: {statuses: [0, 200]}
              })
           );
  self.addEventListener('install', () => {
     self.skipWaiting();
  });
  ```

Made sure new service worker got loaded. When the API call return with status as 200, there is NO cache **apis** created under cache storage. Hence it's not working offline too, see [No cache "apis"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7fZR.png)
 Verified the following,

- Request made to correct URL
- code flow hits registerRoute during service worker installation phase
- There is no error messages. Debug message also not giving any clues. Is there any way to enable more debugging?
- Service worker is registered under proper scope, Debug message `Service Worker registration successful with scope:  http://localhost:8081/dist/`,

API: `http://localhost:5000/dist/abc/123`

API to which call is made, `http://localhost:5000/dist/abc/123/`. Note that it's cross-site call, base page from which the call is made is `http://localhost:8000`. As mentioned before the API call is successful and returns response with status 200.

I am pretty new to serviceworker/workbox. Any directions on this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should try running your app with https and also pass cors parameter in your options

As referred in mdn docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API